# saving the Json file into a specified directory using python

Tags: python, json

I have a python file demo.py, I have created a JSON file using the demo.py file.

```
    def write_json(new_data, filename='Report.JSON'):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json_string=json.dumps(new_data)
            f.write(json_string)
```

This is creating a JSON file in the same directory in which the demo.py is present.
If I want to save this report.json file into some other directory, how can I do that

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would believe you specify a full path for the filename variable.

Comment: You can use like `with open(f'{target_path}{filename}', 'w') as f:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that *filename* in with statement is only the filename and for this reason the file is created in the same directory of the python file.

If you want to have a specific path for the new file, you have to specify the full path for the filename parameter. 
In this way in

```
 with open(filename, "w") as f:
```

the filename variable will contains the whole path and the json file will be saved in the correct directory

Keep in mind that you can also hardcode the path using something like this:

```
import os
def write_json(new_data, filename="Report.JSON"):
    desired_dir = "<custom_dir_here>"
    full_path = os.path.join(desired_dir, filename)
    with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
        json_string=json.dumps(new_data)
        f.write(json_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/MyPath")
```

To change working directory you're in.

Will make your life easier if You are going to work with multiple files